# create a variable xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Good morning, if anyone would know it was helping to create a variable through a xsl and xml

I have this xml:

```
<!ELEMENT bdticketCardell (invoice, services, products) >
........
<!ELEMENT services (service+)>
<!ELEMENT service (nameService, quantityService, priceService)>
<!ELEMENT nameService (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT quantityService (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT priceService (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST service idService ID #REQUIRED>
```

I want to do= ""variable name="grosspriceservice1" select="//quantityService[@idService = "s1"] * //priceService[@idService = "s1"]/>""

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear
please provide XML example to get a clear and better answer. 
As you have DTD you can generate any generic XML sample file without sensible data but correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but my guess is that you want to multiply the price by the quantity for the service which @id is equal to "s1" and put that result in a variable.

If so, you can just write:

```
<xsl:variable name="grosspriceservice1" 
  select="/services/service[@idService='s1']/quantityService * /services/service[@idService='s1']/priceService"/>
```

Or, if your parser processes DTD ids (which should be true in most cases) :

```
<xsl:variable name="grosspriceservice1" 
  select="id('s1')/quantityService * id('s1')/priceService"/>
```

(Of course, you can also use a variable to store the service which id is s1)

The @id attribute is not under `quantityService` or `priceService` but under their common parents and the closest solution to what you were proposing is:

```
<xsl:variable name="grosspriceservice1" 
  select="//quantityService[../@id='s1'] * //priceService[../@idService = "s1"]"/>
```

But this would be much less efficient than the two options I have proposed above since the processor would have to scan over the whole document twice to execute this operation.